# How to populate a dropdown select box by matching contained text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, combobox

I have created two identical dropdown select boxes as below:

**HTML**

```
<select id="ddl1" name="ddl1">
    <option value="1">TEXT 1</option>
    <option value="2">TEXT 2</option>
    <option value="3">TEXT 3</option>
</select>

<select id="ddl2" name="ddl2">
    <option value="1">TEXT 1</option>
    <option value="2">TEXT 2</option>
    <option value="3">TEXT 3</option>
</select>
```

Using jquery I have created code to update the value of one when the other changes and vice versa as below:

**JQUERY**

```
var a = ('#ddl1'),
    b = ('#ddl2');

$(a + ',' + b).change(selectddl);
$(selectddl);

function selectddl() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var text = $(this).text();

    if (this.id === 'ddl1') {
        $(b + ' option[value="' + val + '"]').prop('selected', true);
        $(b).selectmenu('refresh');
    } else if (this.id === 'ddl2') {
        $(a + ' option[value="' + val + '"]').prop('selected', true);
        $(a).selectmenu('refresh');
    }
};
```

My requirements now are to update the select boxes based on their contained **TEXT** and not their value.

---

### QUESTION

How to update a dropdown select box based on another select box contained **TEXT**?

After some research I have tried but failed to do this as below:

**JQUERY**

```
var a = ('#ddl1'),
    b = ('#ddl2');

$(a + ',' + b).change(selectddl);
$(selectddl);

function selectddl() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var text = $(this).text();

    if (this.id === 'ddl1') {
        $(b + ' option[value="' + val + '"]').prop('selected', true);
        $(b).selectmenu('refresh');
    } else if (this.id === 'ddl2') {
        $(a + ' option:contains("' + text + '")').prop('selected', true);
        $(a).selectmenu('refresh');
    }
};
```

## CLICK FOR DEMO

Can anyone explain how this can be achieved?

The correct answer to this question would **NOT** use **contains** due to the conflicts that could arise with text such as:

- TEXT
- TEXT1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.filter()` function to achieve what you are requesting. You will basically need to select all of the options, then call `.filter()`, passing in a function that only accepts the option who's text is equal to what you expect.

For example, your `else if` statement might look like this:

```
else if (this.id === 'ddl2') {
    $(a + ' option').filter(function() {
        return this.text === text;
    }).prop('selected', true);
    $(a).selectmenu('refresh');
}
```

Also, it looks like you need to change your `text` variable as well. You should change it to something that will select the text of the currently selection option, like so:

```
var text = $(this).find(':selected').text();
```

[Here's a working Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XkzJd/1/)